# how to navigate to pasted stack trace visual-studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I remember I used to

navigate to pasted stack trace by clicking

`ctrl + E + T`

is it a resharper utility?

What's the build in equivalent for visual studio 2012?

Comment: *Ctrl+E+T* is indeed a ReSharper short cut for opening *Stack Trace Explorer* and paste Clipboard content in a new tab of it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Stack Trace Explorer is a ReSharper feature. There is no equivalent built into Visual Studio. (If there was, why would they take all the time and expense to add the feature to ReSharper?)

Comment: This is a wrong answer. There were maybe nothing equivalent in past, but with Visual Extensions everything is possible. @Nir found one and I am using it now. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamirBoulema.StackTraceExplorer#review-details

Comment: VS 2022 has this feature. See Matt's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72266691/354009

Answer (score 10):

There is an extension Visual Studio 2017 called 'Stack Trace Explorer', you can get it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamirBoulema.StackTraceExplorer#review-details)

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio 2022 now contains Stack Trace Explorer out of the box.

View -> Other Windows -> Stack Trace Explorer

or

`Ctrl+E, Ctrl+S`

Comment: it seems my source code in the stack trace explorer is not clickable. But the ones from System namespace are. Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace explorer extension does not seem to work with current vscode version, but I found that if I just create a textfile with the stacktrace, and in the terminal type 'cat textfile' then I can Ctrl-click the lines of the stacktrace.  (I'm on linux, 'cat' will print the contents of the file).

Answer (score -2):

Are you looking for ctrl+shift+v ?

Comment: tried that. I paste only. I'm locking for a visual studio window that has clickable links to the code- corresponding to the stack trace